# Can't find the AppData file in order to set up properly the Python Set Path

Tags: python, pip

I wanted to download PIP on windows and I apparently have to set up a path for python. It seems that I have the define the path within has the "AppData" folder, which I can't find.

Comment: The "AppData" folder is usually hidden by default. In the File Explorer in Windows click the Hidden Items checkbox under the "Show/Hide" section.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Is it normal though to not find my Python file in the AppData\Local path, whereas is I can find it in another path ?

Comment: It depends on where it was installed. The AppData folder is usually the default install location but if it was changed during the install then it would be located somewhere else. Here is some information on where to find the location and setting it in your PATH: [link](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/using-pip-on-windows/5)

Answer (score 0):

App data file is hidden by default, it is normal so users cannot accidentally make changes important files, you can uncheck the hide files checkbox, as well as uncheck the hide system files